# Como llamar un resultado de una función fuera de esta?

Tags: python

estaba practicando condicionales y quise hacer un contador de vocales y me sale un error al momento de llamar al contador en el print , eh visto que hay mejores formas de hacerlo como clases o usando self o metodo global , pero eso esta mas avanzado para mi , ojala puedan ayudarme .

```
print(" Hola ,para empezar escriba una palabra y siga las instrucciones ")
palabra=input()
def vocales():
    vocal=["a","e","i","o","u"]
    contador=0
    for i in vocal:
        for j in palabra:
            if (i==j):
                contador+=1
    return contador
print (" presione 1 si desea contar las letras o 2 si desea contar las vocales")
opcion = int(input())
if opcion==1:
    print(len(palabra))
elif opcion==2:
    print("el numero de vocales es  " +  str(contador))
```

En la opcion 2  no me reconoce el contador , y cuando lo pongo como global o fuera de la funcion me sale como 0 ,sin recorrer el for .

Comment: Hola Heli, bienvenida, para concatenar variables con texto debes hacerlo así: **print( f"el numero de vocales es {vocales()}" )**, empezando con **f** luego entre asteriscos la frase, y en ella, y dentro de corchetes, la variable a imprimir (en este caso, la llamada a una función).

Comment: @MarcePuente, No son asteriscos, son comillas dobles, los asteriscos son `*`. De igual forma no es necesario utilizar `fstring` puede hacerlo directo `print("el numero de vocales es  " +  str(vocales()))`.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, jajaj gracias maestro, mi cabeza  está en Marte, por suerte siempre tengo la espalda bien cuidada!!!

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: deberias pasar `palabra` como argumento de la funcion `vocales`. Tal como lo tienes estas usando `palabra` como variable global. Aunque funcione es una mala práctica. Modifica `vocales` para que acepte un parametro `def vocales(palabra)`  y llama a la function pasando el parametro `vocales(palabra)`

Answer (score 3):

Buen día,

En tu función `vocales()` ya estás regresando el contador por lo que bastaría con utilizar el valor que regresa la función en tu `print` tal como @MarcePuente dijo en su comentario.

Fuera de ese punto, quisiera mencionar algunas cosas que puedes optimizar de tu código:

1. En la función `vocales()` no es necesario utilizar dos ciclos `for` anidados, bastaría con un ciclo `for`, de esta forma:

```
def vocales():
    vocal = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    contador = 0
    for i in palabra:
        if i in vocal:
            contador += 1
    return contador
```

El operador `in` se puede utilizar con el ciclo `for` para iterar en cada letra de la palabra y en el condicional `if` para revisar si la letra existe dentro de tu lista de vocales.

2. Tu código no funciona si las palabras están escritas en mayúsculas. Si ingresamos la palabra "AGUA" y utilizamos la opción 2 obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
Hola ,para empezar escriba una palabra y siga las instrucciones 
 AGUA
 presione 1 si desea contar las letras o 2 si desea contar las vocales
 2
el numero de vocales es  0
```

Una forma de corregir esto es convirtiendo siempre todas las letras a minúsculas. Si la palabra ingresada no se va a imprimir tal cual en ningún momento entonces podrías convertir la palabra ingresada a minúsculas con `lower()`, de esta forma:

```
palabra = input().lower()
```

Si la palabra ingresada se va a utilizar más adelante entonces podrías convertir cada letra adentro de tu función `vocales()` de esta forma:

```
def vocales():
    vocal = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    contador = 0
    for i in palabra:
        if i.lower() in vocal:
            contador += 1
    return contador
```

La primera opción sería mejor ya que en la segunda opción la función `lower()` se llama múltiples veces, una vez por cada letra y en la primera opción convierte todas las letras a minúsculas con una sola llamada a la función.

3. Los `input()` permiten ingresar algún `string` para mostrar al requerir la información, eso te permite ahorrarte los `print()` antes de cada `input()`, lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```
palabra = input("Hola, para empezar escriba una palabra y siga las instrucciones:").lower()
```

4. Si utilizamos [`comprensión de listas`](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/) la función vocales podría reducirse de la siguiente forma:

```
def vocales():
    vocal = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    return len([c for c in palabra if c in vocal])
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
palabra = input("Hola, para empezar escriba una palabra y siga las instrucciones:").lower()
opcion = int(input("Presione 1 si desea contar las letras o 2 si desea contar las vocales:"))

def vocales():
    vocal = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    return len([c for c in palabra if c in vocal])

if opcion == 1:
    print(len(palabra))
elif opcion == 2:
    print("El numero de vocales es: " +  str(vocales()))
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenos días!
No pretendo, ni mucho menos mejorar nada de todos los que te han contestado. La única diferencia que te propongo es utilizar un string para trabajar el ejercicio (incluyendo acentos). A parte para que veas las posibilidades he creado una función `longitud()` que hace lo mismo que `len()`.
Suerte...

```
def longitud(y):
    letras = 0
    for j in y: letras+=1    
    return(letras)
        
def contador_de_vocales(x):
    r = 'aeiouAEIOUáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ'
    vocales = 0
    for i in x:
        if i in r: vocales+=1
    return(vocales)

palabra = input('Hola, para empezar escriba una palabra y siga las instrucciones: ')
opcion = int(input('Presione 1 si desea contar las letras o 2 si desea contar las vocales...'))
if opcion== 1: print(f'La palabra \'{palabra}\' tiene {longitud(palabra)} letras')
else: print(f'La palabra \'{palabra}\' tiene {contador_de_vocales(palabra)} vocales')
```

Pruebas

```
Hola, para empezar escriba una palabra y siga las instrucciones:
Programación
Presione 1 si desea contar las letras o 2 si desea contar las vocales...
1
La palabra 'Programación' tiene 12 letras
```

```
Hola, para empezar escriba una palabra y siga las instrucciones:
Programación
Presione 1 si desea contar las letras o 2 si desea contar las vocales...
2
La palabra 'Programación' tiene 5 vocales
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a contar la vocales de _Pingüino_?

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. No quise complicar más las cosas, ya que por ejemplo, hablo una lengua minoritaria que tiene una gran variedad de acentos abiertos, cerrados e incluso circunflejos.

Answer (score 0):

La longitud de la palabra se obtiene con el método `len`.

---

Como existen muchos tipos distintos de acentos, no me parece razonable enumerar todas las vocales, mayúsculas y minúsculas, con sus posibles acentuaciones.
Creo que lo mejor, es normalizar las vocales y comparar con el conjunto de 5 vocales.
El método que usaremos para normalizar las vocales está extraído de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44433664/12575557).

```
from unicodedata import normalize

def vocales(palabra):
    # Separo las vocales de sus acentos
    palabra = normalize('NFD', palabra.lower())
    # Todo lo que no se pueda convertir a ascii, no es una letra
    palabra = palabra.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

    # Conjunto de 5 vocales, lo convierto a ascii
    vocales = set('aeiou'.encode('ascii'))

    # Cuento cuántas letras son vocales
    return sum(1 for letra in palabra if letra in vocales)
```

Fíjate que, en general, siempre que queremos comprobar la pertenencia de un elemento a una colección (en este caso a las 5 vocales) suele tener más sentido usar `set`.
Nos aportará una ligera mejora de rendimiento, pero sobre todo es más canónico.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás enfrentando es que estás intentando acceder a la variable contador fuera de su alcance. La variable contador se declara y se utiliza dentro de la función vocales(), por lo que no está disponible fuera de ella.

Una forma de solucionar esto es almacenar el resultado de la función vocales() en una variable y luego usar esa variable en el bloque if correspondiente. Aquí tienes una versión modificada de tu código:

```
print("Hola, para empezar escriba una palabra y siga las instrucciones")
palabra = input()

def vocales():
    vocal = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    contador = 0
    for i in vocal:
        for j in palabra:
            if i == j:
                contador += 1
    return contador

print("Presione 1 si desea contar las letras o 2 si desea contar las vocales")
opcion = int(input())

if opcion == 1:
    print("El número de letras es:", len(palabra))
elif opcion == 2:
    contador_vocales = vocales()
    print("El número de vocales es:", contador_vocales)
```

En este código, se llama a la función vocales() y se almacena su resultado en la variable contador_vocales. Luego, se utiliza esta variable en el bloque elif para imprimir el número de vocales.

Recuerda que la función vocales() se encarga de contar las vocales en la palabra ingresada. Si deseas contar las letras en general (incluyendo consonantes), puedes eliminar la función vocales() y simplemente usar len(palabra) en el bloque elif.

Comment: Como esta respuesta viene puramente de ChatGPT, se debería borrarla: [está prohibido aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `regex` para extraer las vocales y consonantes de la variable `palabra` y luego llamar `len` sobre el arreglo retornado desde `findall`.

```py
import re

palabra = input('Ingrese numero: ') 
opcion = input('Ingrese numero: ')

def vocales(opcion):
    vocales =  re.compile(r'[aeiou]+')
    no_vocales = re.compile(r'[^aeiou]+')
    return len(vocales.findall(palabra)) if opcion==1 else len(no_vocales.findall(palabra))
```

Ejemplo

```py
>>> res = re.compile(r'[aeiou]+')
>>> res.findall('bale')
['a', 'e']
>>> res = re.compile(r'[^aeiou]+')
>>> res.findall('bale')
['b', 'l']
```